# How to switch back to Old AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was trying to switch back to the old management console of AWS. I found [this in AWS discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=727490) but it seems to be backdated and doesn't work anymore. 
I don't see the `Switch back to previous version` option mentioned there in my dashboard.

My question is how can I switch back to the previous styled web console in AWS?

My current dashboard:

[image: Screenshot with 6 tiles under the title "Build a solution" with a "See more" link and 6 tiles under "Learn to build" with a "See all" link.]

Image mentioned in the forum:

[image: Screenshot of a series of text links with a "Switch back to previous version" link at the bottom of the page.]

**Edit**:
Reason why I want to switch back to the previous panel: I was adding some Lifecycle rules to my S3 bucket. The previous console had better instructions and tooltip helps for adding rules.

Comment: that ship has sailed. what is wrong with the new console?

Comment: well, I was adding some Lifecycle rules to my S3 bucket. The previous console had better instructions and tooltip helps for adding rules.

Answer (score 3):

On the main console page under actions select "revert to previous console". I agree the new console is just terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Click the aws logo on the upper left to get to Console Home, then click the actions button to expose the drop-down menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not 'ACTION' tab to click. There is a 'Reset to Default Layout', but that did not reset to the ECS wizard that I need in the old UI.
I need the older version because I am doing a AWS Challenge Lab at my school, and the steps require input on the ECS wizard, which does not exist in the new UI experience.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/
2. Click "Reset to default layout"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: there's absolutely no section called `actions`

Comment: I cannot remember exactly so I won't argue on whether there is an "Actions" button or not. Now aws has a "Reset to default layout" on the page when I logged in, at least for me. Hope this helps.